# Vue.js for long-term projects

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, single-page-application

I work on a 10-year legacy project with 2.2m lines of code and we are currently studying the possibility of changing the frontend from JSP to SPA. This project is maintained by the government and is a project to work for at least 15 years. Our team thinks about putting Vue.js for the frontend, but we are afraid Vue.js will not live as long. What do you think about that?

Comment: I think 15 year is too long for most of js frameworks... I know at least 2 gov projects based on Vue.js framework. So, my opinion is vue.js is as suitable for the project as a react or angular do